# ngmodule.type - cannot read property type of null - main.js

Tags: angular

I'm trying to update my app to use RC5, so bootstrapping my app using a module.

Getting this error:

[image]

When I click the error and get more info it says:

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13673:45) at Array.forEach (native) at getTransitiveModules (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13672:17) at CompileMetadataResolver._getTransitiveNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13387:37) at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13259:47) at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15845:51) at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15769:41) at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15746:25) at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9991:29) at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9984:25) Error loading http://localhost:3000/js/app/../app/main.js
```

So main.js is the culprit.

Here are my files involved in upgrading to RC5:

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './landing-page/landing-page.component';
import { FindPageComponent } from './find-page/find-page.component';
import { AddPageComponent } from './add-page/add-page.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './shared/navbar.component';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NavbarComponent],
    precompile: [LandingPageComponent, FindPageComponent, AddPageComponent, NavbarComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = "the vegan repository";

    constructor() {

        $('.close').each(function (i, obj) {
            $(this).click(function() {

            })
        });

        $("p").click(function () {
            alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
        });
    }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HighlightDirective } from './highlight.directive';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { routerConfig } from './app.routes';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './landing-page/landing-page.component';
import { FindPageComponent } from './find-page/find-page.component';
import { AddPageComponent } from './add-page/add-page.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './shared/navbar.component';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routerConfig),
    FormsModule, 
    LandingPageComponent,
    FindPageComponent,
    AddPageComponent,
    NavbarComponent
],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HighlightDirective
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

main.ts (please note the first bootstrap is commented out - it is my old one for RC4):

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { Component, ViewChild, provide } from '@angular/core';
import { routerConfig } from './app.routes';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';
import { GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS, LazyMapsAPILoaderConfig } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HighlightDirective } from './highlight.directive';

/*bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  routerConfig,
  disableDeprecatedForms(),
  provideForms(),
  GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS,
  HighlightDirective,

provide(LazyMapsAPILoaderConfig, {useFactory: () => {
    let config = new LazyMapsAPILoaderConfig();
    config.apiKey = 'AIzaSyAPXjwYVEfDZvULTLmh_9XXQn_7d7AYxIw';
    config.libraries = ['places'];
    return config;
  }})

]).catch((err: any) => console.error(err));*/

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule }              from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Why am I getting the error?

Comment: Listing components in `imports` doesn't look right to me `LandingPageComponent,
    FindPageComponent,
    AddPageComponent,
    NavbarComponent`. I didn't dive fully into modules yet and I might miss something though.

Comment: You shouldn't use directives (and, afaik, precompile) anymore in your component, since that's the role of the module. And why do you use jquery in your component? Use angular as it's supposed to be used (for example, `(click)="..."` in the template). Also, `imports` must contain other modules to import, not components. Components should be in declarations.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah but to get the app running with RC5, one should make small changes at a time. Once it is running, then I can make it more RC5. All of your comments are correct but shouldn't be the reason there is an error.

Comment: If you move the components from the imports, to the declarations. does the error go away?

Comment: The last point is probably the most important: you're saying angular "here are some modules to import", but these are not modules at all.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes you are correct. Taking the components from the imports to the declarations fixed the error. Sorry for the confusion in my last comment.

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAlHamali Yes thanks that fixed the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this same issue because I had a component listed in my `imports`.

Components should only go in `declarations`.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#declarations

Here's a concise overview (from the docs) of the main arrays in the `NgModule` decorator:

- `declarations`: A list of the component, directive and pipe classes that belong to this module.
- `providers`: List dependency injection providers (typically Services)
- `imports`: List of supporting modules
- `exports`: A list of declarations — component, directive, and pipe classes — that an importing module can use.

Comment: I had made the mistake of adding my `service` in `@NgModule({declarations:[]})`, **All services should only be listed inside** `providers:[]`

Comment: Note that the `exports` array can also contain module names: When module `A` re-exports module `B`, any other module that imports module `A` will also get access to the exports of module `B`, without the need to import it explicitly via the `imports` array.